# $\{na_{n}\} \subset \ell^{\infty}(\mathbb Z)$ if $a_{n}\in \ell^{1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{a_{n}\} \subset \ell^{1}(\mathbb Z)$ ([Sequence space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space)).

> MY  Question: Can we expect $\{na_{n}\} \subset \ell^{\infty}(\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: As noted, your expectation is incorrect.  However it is correct if the sequence $(a_n)$ is regular enough.  For example, if $(a_n)$ is monotone.

Answer (score 4):

No, we can't expect that. Consider the sequence

$$a_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{k^2} &, n = k^3\text{ for some } k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\} \\
0 &, \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Then $a\in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$, but $(na_n) \notin \ell^\infty(\mathbb{Z})$.